# Issue in invoking AWS Lambda function with API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created a AWS Lambda function and a API Gateway to invoke that function.

In the Resource tab of the APIGateway, if I invoke test, then the test successfully passed and return 200 status but if I deploy the API and invoke the URL mentioned there, I got the following error:

> {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}

Please let me know if I need to pass more information.

Comment: Did you add an authorizer in integration request section?

Comment: No. Please help me what is the role of the authorizer.

Comment: If you add an authrizer, it will require to send a Authorization header, which will be validated. How the validation works depends on the authorizer you add e.g IAM, CognitoAuthorizer, CustomAuthorizer.

Comment: I just added the authorizer, and passed method.request.header.Authorization in the "Identity token source". There is nothing like the type of authorizer , which you have mentioned.

It did not help.

Comment: Sorry my bad, check in method request for auth method (Not in integration request) whether its set or not

Comment: Auth: Not required

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152361/discussion-between-abhishek-mittal-and-ashan).

Answer (score 0):

If methods are defined on child resources and not on the root resource itself, choosing the Invoke URL link will return a {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"} error response. In this case, you must append the name of a specific child resource to the Invoke URL link. It means along with the url generated by API gateway append your resourse name.